# Product of Mobius Band with Itself

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology, continuum-theory

I have a few questions about the Mobius band $M$.  The first two questions are pretty direct, whereas the third is a bit vague.

1. Let $F_2(M)$ denote the collection of non-empty subsets of $M$ with at most two points.  What is the topology of this space under the Hausdorff metric?

Generally, if $X$ is a metric space let $F_n(X)$ be the non-empty subsets of $X$ with at most $n$ points, endowed with the Hausdorff metric.  For example, $F_2(\mathbb{S}^1) = M$.

2. What is $F_4(\mathbb{S}^1)$?
3. Is there a study of the space $M \times M$?  What are some of its most interesting and important properties?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, in general $F_{2n+1}(S^1)\simeq S^{2n+1}$ and $F_{2n}(S^1)\simeq S^{2n-1}$ (homotopy equivalences). Topologically, while $F_2(S^1)\cong M$ and $F_3(S^1)\cong S^3$, things get horrible at $n\geq 4$ (I think these spaces lose even good local properties).

Comment: Do you have a reference for these, or these are your intuitions?

Comment: The computation of $F_2(S^1)$ is an exercise in the book *Hyperspaces* by Nadler and Illanes. The computation of $F_3(S^1)$ is due to [Bott](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0050.17801) (see also [Borsuk](https://eudml.org/doc/213190)). The homotopy equivalences were established by Wu in *Note sur les produits essentiels symétriques des espaces topologiques*. I read a review note at some point which basically said that $n=3$ is the last time you can expect to find a space you will recognise. I don't think anything past the homotopy type is known for $n\geq4$.

Comment: Oh hmm, that's kind of a shame.  I wanted $F_4$ specifically to try to replicate the symplectic proof of the Smooth Toeplitz Square Problem with Whitney functions.  Because the "symplectic" nature of the proof is actually just some topologico-geometric information being presented in a conveniently symplectic form.  But if the local picture gets gnarly it's probably no longer possible.  Not an expert in hyperspaces in general, much less symmetric spaces tho.

Comment: Not a shame at all. You've got a paper when you figure it out ;)

Comment: Tbh it's surprising that $F_4$ would be so nasty; all these spaces $M \times M$, $F_2(M)$ and $F_4(\mathbb{S}^1)$ should sit in each other nicely (after quotienting) in a little sequence, and I wouldn't expect the quotients to be very nasty??